# Is it possible to determine in gdb whether a thread is executing (or blocked) in kernel or user space?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, kernel

Consider the following program.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    sleep(1000);
}
```

If we run `strace` on this program, the last line that appears before the long sleep is the following.

```
nanosleep({1000, 0},
```

While the program is asleep, the code is executing (likely blocked) inside the OS kernel.

When I run the program under `gdb`, if I send `SIGINT` in the middle of the sleep, I can collect various information about the main thread, such as its `backtrace` and various register values.

**Is there is some expression in gdb that evaluates to `true` iff the thread must cross a `syscall` boundary before executing code in userspace again?**

Ideally, there would be a cross-platform solution, but platform-specific solutions are also useful.

**Clarification**: I do not care whether the thread is *actually executing*; only whether its most recent program counter value was in kernel code or user code.

Put another way, can `gdb` tell us whether a particular thread has entered the kernel but not yet exited the kernel?

Comment: You misunderstand how preemptive multitasking works. If a "thread" goes to sleep, the kernel doesn't do anything at all with that thread until it is woken up, it doesn't even run anything internally. Instead it will let other user-space threads and processes run.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm fully aware of that; that's why I said "likely blocked" in the kernel. But that is orthogonal to the question; for the purposes of the question, I consider a thread that is *blocked* (not executing) in the kernel to be in kernel space.

Comment: And to answer what happens when you send the `SIGINT` signal, is that the OS wakes up the sleeping process to handle the signal, and if the process doesn't have a signal handler for `SIGINT` the OS terminates the process. The debugger installs special handlers to catch all signals, but it's handled in user-space.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, The `SIGINT` is only used to break into the debugger so we can examine state; I'm hoping it's not relevant to the question or its answer, but please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: But the process *isn't* in "kernel space". When a process is put to sleep, the kernel puts it in a special queue for processes waiting for events, and then schedules another process to run. The sleeping process itself doesn't do anything, it's not running in user nor kernel space. This can easily be seen using the [`time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command, which will show the kernel-time ("sys" time) as very small.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Would it be more clear if I said "needs to cross a `syscall` boundary" before executing user code again? I literally do not care if it's taking kernel time or not; I only care which side of the kernel crossing the thread is on.

Comment: Try `layout asm`. If the PC points to an instruction just after a `syscall` instruction, the thread is in the kernel execution context. (`syscall` or a `int 0x80` for Linux).

Comment: I don't know what this will help achieve though. For gdb, a `syscall` is a single step execution and it can't "debug " kernel code.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, I was trying to keep the example simple for the question; the ultimate goal is to make it easier to filter out threads which are blocked in the kernel when requesting backtraces in a large multithreaded application. That's why I wanted an expression in gdb.

Comment: `*(short*) ($pc - 2) == 0x50f` works, but it can also be a suffix for other instructions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is some expression in gdb that evaluates to true if the
>   thread must cross a syscall boundary before executing code in
>   userspace again?

You can try to use `catch syscall nanosleep`, see [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html).

`catch syscall nanosleep` stops on 2 events: the one on call to a system call and the one on return from a system call. You can use `info breakpoints` to see the number of hit times of this catchpoint. If it is even, then you should be in user space. If it is odd, then you you should be in kernel space:

```
$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) catch syscall nanosleep 
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'nanosleep' [35])
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       catchpoint     keep y                      syscall "nanosleep" 
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ks1322/a.out 
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.27-8.fc28.x86_64

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall nanosleep), 0x00007ffff7adeb54 in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       catchpoint     keep y                      syscall "nanosleep" 
    catchpoint already hit 1 time
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Catchpoint 1 (returned from syscall nanosleep), 0x00007ffff7adeb54 in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       catchpoint     keep y                      syscall "nanosleep" 
    catchpoint already hit 2 times
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 19515) exited normally]
```

Comment: does this work only for nanosleep, or generic syscalls?

Comment: It works for any syscall by it's name or by it's number, see documentation link.

Comment: It seems that I'd have to enumerate all possible syscalls to use this, which is a little unfortunate, but good to know!

Comment: You can `catch syscall` to set catchpoint on all syscalls at once. Though I don't know how it will be usable for your ultimate goal.